# Why are there different people speaking different parts of the coming of the manna?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, beshalach, mon-manna

When viewing the initial relay to *Bnei Yisra'el* about the mahn, we see different people speaking. All verses mentioned are in Shemot (Ex.) chapter 16.

- verses 6 and 7 - Both and Moshe and Aharon speak
- verse 8 - Only Moshe is speaking. He seems to be saying essentially the same thing as in verse 7, namely at the end - "You're complaining against G-d, not us"
- verse 9 Moshe tells Aharon to tell B'nai Yisra'el that G-d has listened to them.
- verse 10 explains that while Aharon was relaying the message, the cloud appeared.

Why do these different people convey these different messages? Why couldn't everything have been relayed by just Moshe? Afterwards, we see that Moshe relays them much of the details of the mahn rules (don't leave over until the next day, etc.)